# auto create groups directories on user logging in

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

Below is my real and effective UIDs and GIDs. My task is to implement a bash script (Ubuntu 10.10 desktop) which should auto create 3 directories `rtkit`, `admin`, `pr007drdl` (group names) in `/home directory`.

Once I have the bash script, I will create an init start/stop script, so should create directories when user logs in. I am totally new to bash scripting. Please help. Thanks in advance. I have no idea where gids' and uids' stored.

```
uid=10002(sandy) 
gid=119(rtkit) groups=119(rtkit),10001(admin),10003(pr007drdl)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like that:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo mkdir -p /home/{rtkit,admin,pr007drdl} #I use `-p' option to produce no error if exist
sudo chown :admin /home/admin
sudo chown :rtkir /home/rtkit
sudo chown :pr007drdl /home/pr007drdl
```

Group ids are stored in `/etc/group` .
uids are stored in `/etc/passwd` .
You can watch them with `getent` command. For example

```
getent passwd username
```

will return information about user `username`.

But I'm not sure, that you're on the right way with creating directories every system start. It's seems not like unixway (:

Comment: thnx for the information @Rush, This would be static. what if there's a LDAP server, with 5 clients. Say, each time Administrator creates a group on server, and the same has to be reflected on all 5 clients, with respective groups.